# Converting this list of tuples to a dict rounds off floats to 0.0 but a similar list doesn't

Tags: python

In Python 2.7 and 3.6.1, if I do this:

```
print(dict([(9, 0.3864042114900435), (10, 0.3782101167315175), (8, 0.16763561455710688), (7, 0.05233844510566873), (4, 0.0), (5, 0.0), (6, 0.0), (7, 0.0), (8, 0.0), (9, 0.0), (10, 0.0), (11, 0.0)]))
```

I get:

```
{9: 0.0, 10: 0.0, 8: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0, 11: 0.0}
```

Why is it rounding off and what can I do to prevent it?

I thought it was some sort of floating point innacuracy I wasn't aware of in the Python interpreter but if that's the case, then why this:

```
print(dict([(9, 0.3864042114900435), (10, 0.3782101167315175), (4, 0.0)]))
```

returns that (no rounding off):

```
{9: 0.3864042114900435, 10: 0.3782101167315175, 4: 0.0}
```

Comment: You've used the 7, 8, 9, and 10 keys twice each. The dictionary is constructed with whichever appears later in your list of tuples. And those all have value 0.

Comment: Wow, how very stupid of me... I did not see those and they were not supposed to be there. Thanks you so much @thesilkworm !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are overwriting the initial values with 0.0.

7, 8, 9 and 10 appear twice in your first representation and the second values are 0.0.